# Touch Pro 2, ARMs chips, and Floating point instructions

Tags: windows-mobile

Does any one know if the Qualcomm MSM7200A ARM11 in the HTC Touch Pro 2 supports floating point operations?  Is there a way to recognize whether or not a processor supports floating point operations based on it's name?

Comment: Send an email to the company and ask? You should be able to get developer documentation for the device that will let you know everything you might want to know. Of course maybe you'd also need to be a direct licensee, and thus they might not provide it? Also the platform will implement software FP transparently if you use FP, but you presumably might want to use a DSP or SIMD unit in the chip instead?

Comment: I was actually evaluating the potential of Windows Mobile solutions running on this hardware.  Since I won't be custom building any devices the liberty that I have for choosing a processor for a WM solution is low.

Comment: It's based on ARM1136EJ-S (http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=cpu&id=a7200a&c=qualcomm_msm7200a), which has no VFP, so no Floating Point support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. The MSM7200 does *not* support floating operations.

Answer (score 0):

What's even sadder is that the ARMv6 instruction set (ARM11) still doesn't have a divide instruction.  The SIMD instructions of the ARM11 can speed up DCT calculations and pixel averaging, but overall the instruction set isn't that much better than the older ARM9.

Comment: I did a test of the speed of the four basic math operations with different data types. On the TP2 the divide operation on a double data type too 30x as much time as an integer addition (I used integer addition as my baseline).  On a certain device that had a floating point unit double division only took 2x the time of integer addition.

Makes a huge difference.